# Google App Engine proxy to one host

Tags: google-app-engine, proxy

Is there any open source app I can upload to Google App Engine, that proxies all requests (including POST and cookies) to a hostname that I choose?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here](http://www.labnol.org/internet/setup-proxy-server/12890/) you can find a guide and the [source code](http://img.labnol.org/files/proxy.zip) to set up a GAE proxy based on [Mirrorr](https://mirrorrr.appspot.com/), an open-source web caching project by Brett Slatkin.

[Here](http://www.gaecupboard.com/tag/proxy?category=Libraries) is a list of other proxy projects.

Comment: Please bear in mind that proxying any site other than your own via this is very likely a violation of the TOS.